# What are picture descriptions for?

Tags: support, editing

To add a picture to a post you create a text in `[...]` and a number next to it that indicates the number to the image link just like normal links, and add a `!` before it.

While with a normal link the text in brackets is used as the hypertext that the reader will see, the text given for the picture doesn't seem to be readable by a reader without entering "edit" mode and viewing the "source code" of the question.

Is the description text for the picture viewable in any way outside the "edit" mode, or is it viewed only in edit mode, and in that case it can only be used as documentation for the author and editors?

*- I'm aware that this is the same with all the SE sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's alt text. Screen readers (for people with visual disabilities) will read this text. Also, if the image fails to load for some reason, this text will be displayed instead.